# How to return a modified object after updating all the values in it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to add single quotes to all the values in an object that looks like this:

```
{name: "testUser", type: "regular"}
```

The object needs to look like the following:

```
{name: "'testUser'", type: "'regular'"}
```

I'm using `Object.values` to achieve this:

```
Object.values(targetObject).map(value => value = `'${value}'`)
```

Except it's not exactly updating `targetObject`. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(k => { yourObject[k] = \`'${yourObject[k]}'\`; });` . You need to reference the original object, Object.values does **not** provide values by reference.

Comment: The `map` method returns a new object. You need to use `for..in` instead to modify directly the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the original object, you'll need the key. Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key and value, iterate with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and each key with the new value:

```js
const targetObject = {name: "testUser", type: "regular"}

Object.entries(targetObject) // get an array of [key, value] pairs
  .forEach(([k, v]) => targetObject[k] = `'${v}'`) // update the original object keys

console.log(targetObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate through all the entries in the object and update them:

```js
const obj = {name: "testUser", type: "regular"};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  obj[key] = `'${value}'`;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you `for..in` to loop through properties of the object.

```js
const obj = {name: "testUser", type: "regular"}

for (let k in obj){
 obj[k] = `'${obj[k]}'`
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is nice because you don't need to create an additional array like you do with `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could map new objects and collect them to a single object.

```js
var object = { name: "testUser", type: "regular" },
    updated = Object.assign(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: `'${v}'` })));

console.log(updated);
```